# Center-align command bar and/or tabs bar

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, neovim

I'm often using vim fullscreen on an extrawide monitor (multiple splits, including terminals). Because both the command bar and the tabs bar span the full terminal width and are left-aligned, commands and tabs are always located to the far-left of the screen, often far away from the split I'm currently focused on, which is annoying (especially because I like having a terminal split to the left of my editor splits).

**Is there any way to center-align the command bar and/or the tabs bar?**

Here's an illustration of what I'd like to achive (before/after):

[image]

[image]

I am using the latest neovim version (v5 pre-release), so if there's a neovim-only solution, that's fine with me. Also, I don't mind plugins.

Comment: For the tabline, it's probably possible to do, but not very easy. You have to set the `'tabline'` option to call a function that will create a tab line expression for Vim to evaluate. In that function, you can calculate the width and pad it with spaces so it gets centered. For the command-line, I don't think there's a way to move it from the first column, so not sure how you'd go about that...

Comment: But *theoretically* it's possible to create a popup-window that *behaves* like typing `:`—definitely non-trivial though